# About centralizer of group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $C\subseteq G$.

$\mathscr C_G(C) = \{x \in G \mid \text{for every}\ c\in C: xc=cx\} =$

$$\bigcap_{c\in C}{\mathscr C_G(c)}$$

can you prove these

a) if $x$ and $y$ are elements of $\mathscr C_G(C)$ than $xy$ is element of $\mathscr C_G(C)$

b) $C\subseteq \mathscr C_G(\mathscr C_G(C))$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathscr C_G(C)$, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, I can ! What about you ?

Comment: can you help me Surb

Comment: Do not post again the [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930551/properities-of-centraliser-of-group). Show your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathscr C_G(C)$ means "The set of all elements of $G$ that commute with every element of $C$".

a)  Let $x,y \in \mathscr C_G(C)$, meaning that $x \cdot c=c \cdot x$ and $c \cdot y=y \cdot c$ for every  $c \in C$. If we want to prove that $x \cdot y \in \mathscr C_G(C)$, we only have to show that $(x \cdot y) \cdot c = c \cdot (x \cdot y)$ for every $c \in C$. Does this help you?

b) This will be clear if you think about what $\mathscr C_G(\mathscr C_G(C))$ means, in words.

Comment: can I write like this for a :xC=Cx and yC=Cy (xy)C=x(yC)=x(Cy)=(xC)y=C(xy)

Comment: Yea, pretty much :) I assume you mean $c$ instead of $C$. This was the first part then.

Comment: yC={yc: c $\in$ C} I mean C is set

Comment: This is still ok then.